# 22.04LTS trackpad error

Tags: touchpad

After updating to the latest version of ubuntu 22.04LTS, I was no longer able to swipe with three fingers on the trackpad, making it inconvenient to access activities. Please tell me the solution.

use PC : LENOVO thinkpad x280

Comment: What do you mean by *updating to the latest version*?  Are you saying you were using Ubuntu 20.04 & recently upgraded to 22.04? or something else. Which 22.04? as that really matters, eg. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop users recently switched to a newer kernel (6.5 from 23.10 instead of 6.2 from 23.04) thus causing a kernel module change.. but that won't impact all 22.04 LTS users as defaults are set by install media & you didn't mention product let alone install media. Did you make any changes?  We're limited to details you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Ubuntu you upgraded from, this feature could have been removed or disabled as part of an update from your previous version to 22.04. Also, whether this feature is available or not may depend on which interface you use (for example, GNOME (default), KDE Plasma, etc.).

It is likely you have already tried this, but you could open Settings (either by clicking the Settings icon, or running `gnome-control-center` from the Terminal (presuming your Ubuntu installation uses the default GUI, GNOME), navigate to `Mouse & Touchpad` > `Touchpad` and check if your desired feature is available. You could also try disabling and re-enabling your touchpad.

Note: I am using Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur), and this feature is not available for me - and I do not remember it being available when I was using 22.04 (before I upgraded) - but I am not sure.

I hope this helps! I would have posted this as a comment, however I am afraid I do not have enough reputation yet to do so.